# Get next date from weekday in Google Sheets/Excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets-formula

How can one return the next date of a given weekday (it could be either a number 1-7 or names Sunday-Saturday).

For example, if today, on Friday 16-Oct-2009 I passed in:

Friday, it would return today's date 16-Oct-2009
Saturday returns 17-Oct-2009
Thursday returns 22-Oct-2009

[Here is the Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MSbLU_b1UcVb9ZJY9En0SYLiVaB36Lc1mkpsaG8u-4Q/copy)

I have tried this formula:

`=A12+(C12+ MOD(7-day(A12),7))`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I worked out an answer to my own question

Here is the formula

```
=date(year(A12),month(A12), day(A12) + mod(C12+ 7-WEEKDAY(A12),7))
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

=TODAY()+MOD(4 + 7-WEEKDAY(TODAY()),7)

Just replace TODAY() and 4 (weekday#) for your context.

Answer (score -1):

This is the formula you are seeking.

```
=A12+(7-WEEKDAY(A12)+B12)
```

A12 holds the start date. B12 holds the ID of the targeted weekday, e.g. 1 for "Sunday".

A11 must hold a true date, as opposed to a text string that looks like a date. If the latter is the case an error will be displayed. The result is always a date. You can format that date as "dddd" to display a day's name or "dddd, dd-mm-yyyy" to display both date and day.

And here are the mechanics of the formula:- `A12-WEEKDAY(A12)` returns always the ***previous*** Saturday, a date that is always in the past. `A12+(7-WEEKDAY(A12))` inverts that calculation, returning always the ***next*** Saturday. This date is always in the future except when A12 is a Saturday. That's when the result will be = A12.

Having found a stable base, you can just add the day you want to the Saturday you have. Add 1 (for Sunday) and you get a Sunday. Add 7 and you get a Saturday. All these dates will be in the future.

That's all as you want it except that if WEEKDAY(A12) = B12 you want the same date as in A12 which is a week earlier than the one the formula prefers. This is where I went wrong while in haste. My apologies! This is the correct modification of the formula's result, to wit, conditionally deduct 7 from the calculation.

```
=A12+(7-WEEKDAY(A12)+B12)-IF(WEEKDAY(A12)=B12,7,0)
```

Comment: I think I am not getting the correct expected result. I have applied your formula in G15 cell https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MSbLU_b1UcVb9ZJY9En0SYLiVaB36Lc1mkpsaG8u-4Q/edit#gid=468527821 The expected result after adding Weekday number 6 is 30th July (Friday). It should have displayed the immediate Friday instead of next week Friday